# Stop running tests in xml suite if first test class fails

Tags: xml, selenium-webdriver, testng, build-automation

When running the test suite, i want tests 2-9 only execute if test1 passes, and not run otherwise. Test 1 ensures that preconditions for tests 2-9 are met. Here is a sample xml segment:

```
<suite name="suite1">
<test name="test suite">
    <parameter name="selenium.browser" value="firefox" />
    <classes>
        <class name="test1" />
        <class name="test2" />
        <class name="test3" /> 
        <class name="test4" />
        <class name="test5" />
        <class name="test6" />
        <class name="test7" />
        <class name="test8" />
        <class name="test9" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

I'm using testng with selenium webdriver to run the tests. I think it has something to do with the dependency tag but i'm not sure how it works, as im new to xml. I've read that the tag can be used to link dependencies on other projects, but what about dependencies between individual classes within the  tag? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is test1 a setup method or are you testing something in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `group` and `dependsOnGroups` features: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods

In your case "test1" should be in a group and "test2-9" should be in another group, dependend of the first one.

Comment: i had already figured it out thanks! This is what i did so upvoted it